# Configuration error with Spork?: `require': no such file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, spork

I'm new to Ruby & Rails, and am currently working on the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).  Specifically I am currently working on the part of the book where I need to [setup Spork](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec%3aspork).

Unfortunately when I enter

```
spork
```

I get

```
Using RSpec
  -- Rinda Ring Server listening for connections...

  -- Starting to fill pool...
     Wait until at least one slave is provided before running tests...
  ** CTRL+BREAK to stop Spork and kill all ruby slave processes **
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load --
magazine_slave (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from magazine_slave_provider.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

with the last 4 lines repeating.

Ok, simple enough, it appears to be a problem in lib/rubygems/custom_require.

The project lib dir doesn't contain a rubygems subdirectory, so I'm assuming it's in the ruby directory; but it isn't.  So is rubygems some kind of virtual dir?

```
$ dir *custom_require*.* /s/b
```

Yeilds

```
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\1.9.1\rubygems\custom_require.rb
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\doc\rubygems-1.6.2\rdoc\lib\rubygems\custom_require_rb.html
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rubygems-update-1.6.2\lib\rubygems\custom_require.rb
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\site_ruby\1.9.1\rubygems\custom_require.rb
```

So the html file obviously isn't it, and line 29 on the following files have comments.

```
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rubygems-update-1.6.2\lib\rubygems\custom_require.rb
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\site_ruby\1.9.1\rubygems\custom_require.rb
```

There is code on line 29 of

```
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\1.9.1\rubygems\custom_require.rb
```

But when I commented out the code, I still got the error, and when I removed comments on lines before 29, the error line number did not change.

Can anybody throw me a bone as to what this might be?

Comment: I understand it is looking for the *magazine_slave* file. My thought is, since it is attempting to load it from the *custom_require* file, then *custom_require* file would be place to start diagnosing the problem. Does that sound right? ... as I said, I'm very new to ruby and wouldn't have a clue if there is something very basic that I'm missing. (thx for the comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's what I did to solve the problem.

I'm not totally thrilled with the solution, and feel it leaves many more unanswered questions, but it may provide a hint to future people with similar problems.

1. I originally installed BitNami Ruby before RubyInstaller, so I thought there might be configurations somewhere that was at least partially using Bitnami, instead of RubyInstaller.  So I uninstalled RubyInstaller, the BitNami.  Then I reinstalled RubyInstaller and reran all gem installs etc, from the tutorial.
2. Unfortunately, while I no longer got the error above, I was getting a different one.

   `magazine_slave_provider.rb:5:in 'require': no such file to load -- magazine_slave (LoadError)
           from magazine_slave_provider.rb:5:in '<main>'`

   At least I could find this file & I solved this, by replacing `require 'magazine_slave'` with `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/magazine_slave'`

This seemed to resolve the problem for me, although it does seem like I just covered up a sympton of a bigger issue.  It seems unlikely this is the actual problem when nobody else seems to be having this problem.

Comment: I had this problem and changing the magazine_slave_provider.rb did solve the problem.

Comment: It was a bug (in at least spork 0.8.5): https://github.com/timcharper/spork/issues/46 but has been resolved. See the ticket for the "workaround", similar to @Timid Developer.